# What does "be accounted with" mean?

Tags: meaning

It is from this [video](https://youtu.be/gqF8EoDMSGo). It is at around 5 minute and 11 second. Here is the context:

> While the lats, you know, serve a very important role of stability, shoulder health, they are not the prime movers of the bar and should not **be** **accounted with** the training of the prime movers, chest and triceps.

I understand what the speaker means from the context, but I cannot get what *account with* means exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could paraphrase **shoud not be accounted with the training of the prime movers**  as "should not be reckoned part of the training of the prime movers" or "should not be considered (as) part of the training of the prime movers".

Comment: Do you think it may have been a slight misspeak? That can be a problem with analyzing speech too closely.

Comment: @J.R. An older meaning of **account** is "to regard, to consider, to treat, to reckon". It functions like a copular/predicative verb with a nominal subject-complement (what used to be called a "predicate nominative").. Here I think the preposition **with** is somewhat elliptical.  *should not be accounted part of the prime movers' training regimen*